# Need to find latest file in multiple folders with a pattern and move to another server

Tags: wildcards

I have several folders on one server numbered 1-10. Each folder has multiple files. I need to find the latest file with a pattern name for example :

- file 1 : NA_UW_CLUSTER_RESULTS_210916.zip
- file 2 : UW_CLUSTER_RESULTS_210916.zip

I need to select 'file 2' and copy it to another server having multiple corresponding folders numbered 1-10.

So i need to copy latest file (`UW_CLUSTER_RESULTS_210916.zip`) with matching pattern from 'folder 1' in 'A' server to 'folder 1' in 'B' server.

Comment: What you did, till now, for the solution

Comment: I have found the latest file using the command : ls -1rt UW_CLUSTER_RESULTS* | tail -1 However, i cannot use that as different folders will have different prefix to file names e.g. MH_CLUSTER_RESULTS

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is good enough for your use case:

```
ls -1 -td /dir1/prefix1* /dir2/prefix2* | head -n 1
```

Or more robust:

```
find /dir1 /dir2 -type f \( -path "*dir1/prefix1*" -o -path "*dir2/prefix2*" \) -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -n | tail -1 | cut -f2- -d" "
```

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
set -o extendedglob

for folder ('folder '<->(n/))
  scp $folder/*CLUSTER_RESULTS_[0-9](#c6).zip(om[1]) B:$folder/
```

That uses a few of zsh advanced glob operators:

- `<->`, that's `<5-20>` operator to match on numbers, but here with no bound so matches any decimal integer number
- `[0-9]`: in zsh that matches only on 0123456789 characters (and not the hundreds more that other shells typically match).
- `(#c6)`: similar to extended regexps `{6}`: matches 6 of the preceding thing so here digits (requires `extendedglob`).
- `(om[1])`: that part is the glob qualifiers. `om` to `o`rder by `m`odification time (newest first), `[1]` to pick the first. The folder glob also uses a glob qualifier, `n` to order the glob result numerically (so `folder 10` is processed after `folder 9`, not in between `folder 1` and `folder 2`). `/` to restrict to files of type directory.